# How to find and delete multiple files

Tags: delete

I'm wanting to find multiple files as in

```
 find /etc/ /usr/ -type f,d -size +1k -exec ls -slah {} /; -exec rm -riv {} +
```

My question to you is how can I delete only the file size 5k and below with the -exec option

Comment: Words? Files? Which is it?

Comment: Also note that manually deleting files from system directories in this way has ***Bad Idea*** written all over it

Comment: Why, please elaborate !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to:

1. Look for files under `/etc` and `/usr`
2. Select only those files which are under 5k in size
3. Delete them

In that case, what you want is this:

```
find /etc /usr -type f -size -5k -delete
```

Notice that there is no need for -exec, since you can simply use the -delete option.

In your question you wrote `-size +1k`. Did you mean to ask about finding files which are **between** 1k and 5k in size? If that was the case, then you can simply specify the `-size` option twice:

```
find /etc /usr -type f -size +1k -size -5k -delete
```